Google Sheet - How to split this cell?
In google sheet. I need a formula to split this a cell which contains a text divide by brackets. There are four values between these brackets. I need to separate these values in single cells:
UPDATE: the regex must to play with the colon : character to exclude strings like this [vc_row]no-in-new-cell[\vc_row]
RIGHT NOW I USE THIS FORMULE: split(regexreplace(A3;"[.*?]";"|");"|") BUT IT INCLUDES THE CELL G3.
THIS SHOULD NOT HAPPENS
Google sheet file (editable): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bfw3ARYvBKk4JSAC7DB0ip7GzBZCmu2rnUJssm8TsWw/edit?usp=sharing
ORIGINAL CELL
[:en]DRY[:es]SECO[:fr]SEC[:nl]DROGE[:]

INTO THESE FOUR CELLS:
DRY 
SECO  
SEC 
DROGE




You may try:
=split(regexreplace(A3;"\[.*?\]";"|");"|")



Works fine. But if the cell contains something like this [vc_row]no-in-new-cell[\vc_row]this is also splitted. Can you make that the separator to only match the brackt with the colon [:?
Please, take a look:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bfw3ARYvBKk4JSAC7DB0ip7GzBZCmu2rnUJssm8TsWw/edit?gid=0#gid=0

This is the formula: =split(regexreplace(A3;"\[:.*?\]";"|");"|")
